# Error while using the YouTube Data API

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to use the YouTube Data API to extract comments from a video and for that I have an API server key from the Google developers page. My code is in python. I wrote the following statement according to the official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list) to instantiate a service object.

```
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey='my_key')
```

However, I get the following error:

```
user@laptop:~/projects/MLproject$ python scrape.py
WARNING:root:No module named locked_file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/__init__.py", line 38, in autodetect
from . import file_cache
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py", line 32, in <module>
ImportError: No module named locked_file
```

Answer (score 0):

the oAuth2 client that the python google API client builds against recently introduced some changes that broke Google's libs. This was discovered several days ago and documented here:

https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/pull/182

It has now been fixed, and a new build of the python API libs is available (version 1.5):

https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/releases/tag/v1.5.0